# Call a function with req,res params

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making an API on NodeJS with Express. I have a function in the schema Products who return a product by id. The signature of this function is like this:

```
let getProductsById = (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Producto.findById(id)
        .populate('categoria')
        .populate('marca')
        .exec((err, producto) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: err
                });
            }
            if (!producto) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: {
                        message: 'Producto no encontrado'
                    }
                });
            }
            productoResponse = {
                _id: producto._id,
                codigo: producto.codigo,
                descripcion: producto.descripcion,
                nombre: producto.nombre,
                precioCosto: producto.precioCosto,
                precioVenta: producto.precioVenta,
                categoria: {
                    _id: producto.categoria._id,
                    nombre: producto.categoria.nombre
                },
                marca: {
                    _id: producto.marca._id,
                    nombre: producto.marca.nombre
                }
            }
            res.json({
                ok: true,
                producto: productoResponse
            });
        });
}
```

If you don't want to read the entire function, in resume this return a object with some info in it.

I call this function in the router like this:

```
app.get('/producto/:id', function(req, res) {
    getProductsById(req, res);
});
```

This works fine, but I want in another schema (Cart) to call this function to recive a product. In the service of Cart I have this function:

```
let addCart = (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;
    let cart = new Cart({
        user: body.user,
        products: body.products,
        pay: body.pay,
        address: body.address,
        phone: body.phone,
        moreInfo: body.moreInfo,
        total: body.total
    });
    cart.products.forEach(product => {
        console.log(product._id);
        req.params.id = product._id;
        let productX = getProductsById(req,res);
    });
}
```

But this don't work, I have a error that says:

```
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\server\services\productService.js:57:40
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4832:16
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4855:21
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4407:11
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4834:13
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

How can I resolve this problem? Ty.

I resolve doing this way (don't follow my steps is bad and I need to restructure the code)

```
carrito.productos.forEach(producto => {
        console.log(producto._id);
        let id = producto._id;
        Producto.findById(id)
        .exec((err, productoObtenido) => {
            if (err) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!productoObtenido) {
                return false;
            }
            producto.precioVenta = productoObtenido.precioVenta;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here

```
cart.products.forEach(product => {
    console.log(product._id);
    req.params.id = product._id;
    let productX = getProductsById(req,res);
});
```

So you're calling `res.send` multiple time from `getProductsById`

They express refuse it.

Comment: You'll probably think I'm rude but your code is just trash. Nothing good there, awful design. And it's absolutely normal since you try learning express, mongo and API at the same time. Quite difficult. Follow some tutorials about Express+Mongo instead of trying to figure it out by yourself will save you lot of time. Then you'll try to follow your own way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should restructure your app.
Move your actual business logic on a layer behind the request and response handling.
That way you can reuse services/functionality without passing the request and response objects around, which makes your code way harder to write and to understand.